# Oracle stored procedure called from a Spring Boot Program not making any changes in Database

Tags: java, spring-boot, stored-procedures

I have a function that returns true even though the procedure is not properly executed. Below is the function used to call the procedure.
This function/task must be executed through a procedure. It would be great if anyone could suggest what could be the issue. I have spent way too much time on the issue.

The java program is written with Spring boot 2.0.5

```
public boolean doSomeThing(Argument 1, Argument 2) {
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withProcedureName("ProcedureName");

        Map<String, Object> inParamMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        inParamMap.put("Parameter1", Argument 2);
        inParamMap.put("Parameter2", Argument 1);
        inParamMap.put("Parameter3", "");
        inParamMap.put("Parameter4", "some text");
        inParamMap.put("Parameter5", "");
        inParamMap.put("Parameter6", "");
        inParamMap.put("Parameter7", "some text");
        inParamMap.put("Parameter8", null);
        inParamMap.put("Parameter9", null);
        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);

        simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
        return true;
}
```

DB: Oracle
Version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Things I tried

1. Changed Ojdbc6 to Ojdbc8 => No effect
2. Replaced the procedure call with an update query which essentially did the same thing, the query executed properly.
3. Instead of SimpleJdbcCall I tried to use CallableStatement, it also did not work.
4. Executed the procedure manually with dbeaver using the same parameters, it executed correctly.

Comment: I take it you’re not seeing any exceptions? Does the execute method return anything?

Comment: Check you properties file, it should not have spring.datasource.auto-commit=false

Comment: @SamOrozco, No exceptions at all, the execute method does not return anything

Comment: @Pale, we have not defined any commit related property in application.properties. The procedure itself has a commit statement in its declaration statement.

Comment: The only other thing that I would suggest is to debug into that method as far as you can and see what is actually happening.